# Minitest - How do you test a method isn't invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm trying to check if a method isn't invoked within an `after_update` callback.

I'm currently doing:

```
class Foo
  def self.call; end
end

def Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :do_something

  def do_something
    return unless title_changed?

    Foo.call
  end
end
```

In the test it works like that:

```
test 'Foo.new.bar is invoked' do
  mock = Minitest::mock.new
  mock.expect :call, nil
  Foo.stub(:call) { update_record_to_fire_callback }
  mock.verify 
end
```

And it beautifully pass, but now I'm trying to do the opposite but without luck as I don't know how to do it. If I do `assert_not mock.verify` Minitest complains anyway for the method to be executed.

Or maybe there are other way to check a method isn't invoked? The method will do an expensive request, so, I want to avoid that.

I'm using Rails 5 and sadly Minitest. I'm open to add any gem that can work with these versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're open to adding a gem, [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) works well for this. Add the gem, then use mocha's [Expectation#never](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/floehopper/mocha/Mocha%2FExpectation:never). Your test can then look like:

```
test 'Foo.new.bar is not invoked' do
  model = Model.new
  Foo.expects(:call).never
  model.update!(not_the_title: 'value') 
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I just realized `mocha/mini_test` was in the test_helper, so I ended up using something `never` and updated the mocks also to use mocha expectations. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to stub the method that you want to ensure isn't called and have it raise an error.

```
class ModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "does not call Foo.call when title is not changed" do
    model = Model.new
    refute model.title_changed?

    Foo.stub(:call, -> { raise "Foo was called!" }) do
      model.title = "something new"
    end

    assert model.title_changed?
  end
end
```

There is no assertion to check that an error was not explicitly raised. Rails does have [`assert_nothing_raised`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_nothing_raised), but Minitest [does not](http://www.zenspider.com/ruby/2012/01/assert_nothing_tested.html). You can add it if you like.

```
class ModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "does not call Foo.call when title is not changed" do
    model = Model.new
    refute model.title_changed?

    Foo.stub(:call, -> { raise "Foo was called!" }) do
      assert_nothing_raised do
        model.title = "something new"
      end
    end

    assert model.title_changed?
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see the point on creating stubs to do this when the only thing I want is a mock to set up expectations. Anyway, I'm not expecting any error to raise, so the last code advice isn't what I'm looking for.